# Extract hexadecimal values from a percent encoded URL

Tags: java, percent-encoding, urldecode

Let's say for example i have URL containing the following percent encoded character : %80

It is obviously not an ascii character.

How would it be possible to convert this value to the corresponding hex string in Java.
i tried the following with no luck.Result should be 80.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(byteArrayToHexString(URLDecoder.decode("%80","UTF-8").getBytes()));
    }
    public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] bytes)
    {
      StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
      for(int i=0; i<bytes.length; i++)
      {
        if(((int)bytes[i] & 0xff) < 0x10)
        buffer.append("0");
        buffer.append(Long.toString((int) bytes[i] & 0xff, 16));
      }
      return buffer.toString();
  }
```

Comment: If it is the `80` you need, why don't you just strip the percent symbol? Btw, what do you need that for? - Additionally, note that Java characters are 16-bit, i.e. you'll get 2 bytes and depending on the character both bytes might be non-zero (i.e. not 0x00 ).

Comment: I need to extract the contents of a binary SMS from kannel , the url is sent in the following format : http://localhost:8080/rest/MO?source_no=13013&dest_no=%2B2304232381&message=%00+%11%15%00%15%00%00%00%00.%81s%16%FCG%D9%89%B8lQi%8D%EA%D6%F2%C1%7B%01%3DL%D9%1B%B4&udh=%02p%00'  i need to decode the message parameter. Some characters are in HEX , the others are in ascii. I thought URLDecoder would be able to do that. You are right in saying i could implement this but am wondering if there are any functions out there to handle this.

Comment: Those non-ascii parameters are not part of some hex string so why do you want to convert that to hex again? Just use `URLDecoder.decode(...)`, that will do. I don't see the sense of converting `€` (`%80`) to a hex string again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to deal with this is to parse the url using either `java.net.URL` or `java.net.URI`, and then use the relevant getters to extract the components that you require.  These will take care of decoding any %-encoded portions in the appropriate fashion.

The problem with your current idea is that `%80` does not represent `"80"`, or `80`.  Rather it represents a byte that further needs to be interpreted in the context of the character encoding of the URL.  And if the encoding is UTF-8, then the `%80` needs to be followed by one or two more %-encoded bytes ... otherwise this is a malformed UTF-8 character representation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see what you are trying. However, I'll give it a try.

- When you have got this String: `"%80"` and you want to got the **string** `"80"`, you can use this:

  ```
  String str = "%80";
  String hex = str.substring(1); // Cut off the '%'
  ```
- If you are trying to extract the **value** `0x80` (which is `128` in decimal) out of it:

  ```
  String str = "%80";
  String hex = str.substring(1); // Cut off the '%'
  int value = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
  ```
- If you are trying to convert an int to its hexadecimal representation use this:

  ```
  String hexRepresenation = Integer.toString(value, 16);
  ```